# Scala Syntax Help Currying

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying

I came across some code in scala in a similar form like this:

```
  def test1(f : Int => Int)(x : Int) = x + f(x)

  def test2(f : Int => Int)(x : Int) = f(x)

  test2(test1(x => 2*x))(2)
```

I'm confused, so function test1 takes a function and a Int as parameters, and returns a function, right? Then how can `test1(x => 2*x)` be valid and returns a function to test2? Apparently it takes 2 asthe integer parameter, but why? How does the statement `test2(test1(x => 2*x))(2)` expand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
test2(test1(x => 2*x))(2)
```

expands to this:

```
test2(y => test1(x => 2*x)(y))(2)
```

Scala's methods with multiple argument lists can act a lot like curried functions in other languages, but in fact are implemented as methods that requires all of their parameters, and this does show through in the syntax. For example if you put this into the REPL:

```
test1(x => 2*x)
```

It will complain about missing arguments. What this syntax does allow is "eta-expansion", where a method is converted into a function. If you write:

```
val func: Int => Int = test1(x => 2*x) _
```

You can get a function that represents `test1` partially applied. Scala will do eta-expansion automatically if the context requires it, which is what happens with `test2(test1(x => 2*x))(2)`. Note that `test1` itself never returns a function, but the compiler will build a function based on it when required.

However, if you define `test1` like:

```
def test1(f : Int => Int) = (x : Int) => x + f(x)
```

Then the compiler will accept `test1(x => 2*x)` without the `_`. Also, in the underlying implementation there will be only one class implementing the closure retured by `test1`, whereas with the original definition every partial application of `test1` causes a new class to be created for it. On the other hand, it is less efficient when given both parameters, because the closure is always created.

Comment: Okay, so can I say Scala in this case is using eta-expansion to implement function currying, but it encourages us to think that     test1 returns a function?

Comment: Sort of. There are plenty of docs that suggest that multiple parameter lists implement currying, but you can't just blindly use it like you can with real currying, and most instances of methods with multiple parameter lists are not meant to be used partially applied, e.g. `list.foldLeft(0)` is rare. See my new edit - I show how you can create a true curried method/function.

Answer (score 1):

> function test1 takes a function and a Int as parameters, and returns a function, right?

No, it only takes a function as its argument and returns a function. The returned function then takes an int as the argument and returns an int.

> Then how can test1(x => 2*x) be valid and returns a function to test2?

I hope that's clear now.

> How does the statement test2(test1(x => 2*x))(2) expand?

`test1` is called with `x => 2*x` as the argument and returns a function. Then `test2` is called with that returned function as its argument and returns another function. Then that other function is called with `2` as its argument.

Comment: Thank you! I am so dwelled on the imperative programming style, thought currying was just a syntactic sugar. This now makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This isn't really correct. Try `test1(x => 2*x)` by itself inside the REPL.