# Scala Currying syntax explanation

Tags: scala

I am new to scala .

I want to understand the syntax of this below code

```
object PlainSimple {

 def main(args:Array[String])
 {
 val m = add(5) 
 println(m(3))
 }

 def add(x:Int):Int=>Int =
 {
  y=>y+x 
 }

}
```

My question is where are we saying that the add function is returning another function?

What does `Int=>Int` mean?

Inside the add function what is called `y`? Why are we using it without declaring it anywhere?

What do need to do if want multiples line inside add method?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086444/scala-syntax-help-currying?rq=1

Comment: Your question is a good one, but it has nothing to do with currying.  SO documentation has [multiple examples](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/1636/currying#t=201608051605514578482) of currying and advice on its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is Where are we saying that the add function is returning another function?
>
> What is Int=>Int means?

`T => U` as a type means "a function that takes a `T` and returns an `U`". So when we write `: Int => Int` at the end of the function signature, we say "this function returns a function from `Int` to `Int`".

> Inside the add function what is called y ? Why are we using it without declaring it anywhere?

As an expression `x => body` (or `(x,y,z) => body` for multiple parameters) is a function literal, that is it defines an anonymous function whose parameter is named `x` and whose body is `body`. So we are declaring the parameter `x` by writing its name of the left side of the `=>`.

> What do need to do if want multiples line inside add method?

You can put anything to the right of `=>` that you could also put to the right of `=` when defining a method using `def`. So if you want your function's body to consist of multiple statements, you can use braces just like with a regular method definition:

```
y => {
  val z = y+x
  z*2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> My question is Where are we saying that the add function is returning another function?

Right here

```
def add(x: Int): Int => Int = y => y + x
```

`Int => Int` is a function type. That's just syntactic sugar, but you can also write it as

```
def add(x:Int): Function1[Int, Int] = y => y + x
```

Now, what is `y`? `y => y + x` is a lambda, i.e. an anonymous function. This lambda takes one parameter that we're now referring to as `y`.

Here's a good reference on anonymous functions in scala and their syntax: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html

In order to have multiple lines inside the method just use braces

```
def add(x:Int): Function1[Int, Int] = { y =>
  println("whaveter")  
  y + x
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you may add an explanation about `def add(x:Int)(y:Int) : Int = y+x` and calling it with `add(5) _`.